# MongoDBForm error "ValueError:A document class must be provided"

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

Hi i am creating a simple Sign Up form with django framework and mongodb. Following is my view:

```
class SignUpView(FormView):
    template_name='MnCApp/signup.html'
    form_class=EmployeeForm()
    succes_url='/success/'
```

Following is my model:

```
class Employee(Document):
    designation=StringField()
    department=StringField()
    emp_name=StringField(max_length=50)
    password=StringField(max_length=10)
```

Following is my `forms.py`

```
class EmployeeForm(DocumentForm):
    class meta:
        desigs=(
        ('D','Director'),
        ('GM','General Manager'),
        ('AM','Assistant Manager'),
        ('A','Associates')
            )
        deptts=(
            ('HR','Human Resources'),
            ('IT','IT Support'),
            ('TT','Technical Team'),
            ('SM','Sales and Marketting'),
            ('SS','Support Staff')
            )
        document=Employee
        fields='__all__'
        widgets={
             'designation':Select(choices=desigs),
             'department':Select(choices=deptts)
             }
```

Following is the traceback ValueError recieved on loading SignUpview
Traceback:

> File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
>     39.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
>     68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
>     88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get
>     174.         return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get_context_data
>     93.             kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get_form
>     45.         return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\mongodbforms\documents.py" in **init**
>     353.                 raise ValueError('A document class must be provided.')
>
> Exception Type: ValueError at /signup/
>   Exception Value: A document class must be provided.

I am not able to find root of this problem. I am new to django and this is my first project. Also is their anyother way for creating model forms for mongo documents??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your inner class should be called `Meta`, not `meta`.

Comment: This solved above error but generated another one. "FieldError: Unknown field(s) (l, _, a) specified for Employee"

Comment: Looks like that library doesn't recognise the `__all__` syntax. Try omitting the `fields` definition altogether.